# How to remove elements from variadic template argument?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, variadic-templates

I'm trying to remove the first element of a variadic template argument.
The code goes like this:

```cpp
template<typename ...T>
auto UniversalHook(T... args)
{
    //I want to remove the first element of `args` here, how can I do that?
    CallToOtherFunction(std::forward<T>(args)...);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got a little help, and found the solution:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Function(3,5,7);
    return 0;
}
template<typename ...T>
auto CallToAnotherFunction(T&&... args) 
{
    (cout << ... << args);
}

template<typename ...T>
auto Function(T&&... args) {
    /*Return is not needed here*/return [](auto&& /*first*/, auto&&... args_){ 
        return CallToAnotherFunction(std::forward<decltype(args_)>(args_)...); 
    }(std::forward<T>(args)...);
}

//Output is "57"
```

Answer (score 4):

How about trying the direct approach.

```
template<typename IgnoreMe, typename ...T>
auto UniversalHook(IgnoreMe && iamignored, T && ...args)
{
    //I want to remove the first element of `args` here, how can I do that?
    return CallToOtherFunction(std::forward<T>(args)...);
}
```

(also fixed to use forwarding references, and added the obvious `return` )

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I cant modify the Arguments of the Function, also the return Type is not needed, because the function can also have no return type.

Thanks for your reply tho!

Also I just got help from some other dude and he gave me some working code.